# How to Insert - Select Matrix table values in Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

I have 3 different table and each table has Rows and Columns. [r,c]

One of my table has 30 rows and 18 columns,
The second one has 18 rows and 16 columns,
And the last one has 12 Rows and 17 columns.

Number of rows and columns are constant.

I will enter values to this tables. And then I want to save all of this tables to Sqlite. My reference value for insert/select is SheetMetarial.

```
Instert Into {Table1} (col1, col2...) Values (@col1, @col2, ...)
```

or

```
SELECT {SheetMetarial} FROM {Table1};
```

This way is totally not usefull. So I now my rows(Value1, Value2, ... Val30) and also my columns (Column1, column2, ...) for three tables. What is the best way to make this happen?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know what your question is, but if I understood it from the title, you want to insert a multidimensional matrix inside the exact database?
If yes, then you could make a loop over every row in your array (I usually use a matrix inside a multidimensional array) and just apply the columns in its place. Is it that what you mean?

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) maybe helps you, because there you see a sqlite syntax example for inserting multiple rows, if you want.